# Excel Formula - Sum in some Column If Cell in The Same Row in Different Column is NOT Blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for some formula that will sum for me specific column - AP but with few conditions.

I have 2 worksheets that are relevant - "Final" and "Visual".
In "Final" WS I have all the employee numbers in column A. One row for each employee. In Visual WS I have few rows for each employee with the employee numbers in column A too.

I need a formula that will sum to Final worksheet just the rows from column AP in "Visual" that are standing in few standards:

1. The employee Number in that row of column AP in "Visual" worksheet will be the same as in the row in Final sheet - where I want to show the result. It means that the data is of the same specific employee.
2. The row of the number in column AP in "Visual in column AF is NOT blank.

I tried few versions of SUMIFS and it didn't work, That what was not working:

> =SUMIFS(Visual!AP:AP,Visual!A:A,A3,Visual!AF:AF,"<>0")
>   =SUMIFS(Visual!AP:AP,Visual!A:A,A3,OFFSET(Visual!AF:AF,0,10),"<>0")

if it looks like this:

```
column A | column AF |column AP
6655     |120        |120
6655     |152        |152
6655     |0          |500
6655     |0          |259
2541     |589        |589
2541     |0          |89
3268     |15         |15
```

In the example I need to sum for employee 6655 just first two rows of AP column

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried SUMIFS?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, I wrote it in my massage

Comment: You should post the ones that did not work so we do not retry them

Comment: @ScottCraner edited

Comment: searching for non blank is `"<>"` not `"<>0"`  See my answer below

Comment: I thought searching for not blank was "<>"&"".  never knew you could just get away with just the does not equals

Comment: Clarification....and in line with what Scott Craner is saying....0 is not the same as blank.  Do you want blanks excluded, 0 excluded, or both zero and blank excluded?

Comment: and the answer you are looking for is 272?  your first formula that you said does not work gives that number

Comment: @ForwardEd - yes, I am looking for formula that will give me for emp 6655 the answer 272 and for 2541 the answer 589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are entering this formula on the "FINAL" worksheet, and the employee ID is in A3.  Use the following formula and copy down.

```
=SUMIFS(Visual!AP:AP,Visual!A:A,A3,Visual!AF:AF,"<>"&"")
```

#### Update

I see your sample data and thank you for that.  There is a bit of confusion over blank and zero.  I edited your example data to include a blank.  I also provided three separate formulas.  Which one is giving the correct value if any?

[image: poc]

Comment: are you sure there are not empty cells in Visual!AF:LAF that contain spaces?  visually they would look the same but would not be considered empty by sumif

Comment: I need to sum in AP column all thos cells that contains in same row Emp number and in AF column not blank. Now it sums all the nembers that I have for specific Employee. I need to sum to each employee just the rows the are not equal to 0 in AF column.

Comment: I work in insurance company and I am not allowed to toss data in the net, I will try to explain my self better in the original post with editing

Comment: I need the third formula - but I dont know how to transform it to my needs, can you herlp me with that? The one with 272 answer

Comment: change the cell references in my formula to match the cell references on your spread sheet.  A:A means the entire Column A  If the range is on another sheet from where the formula is it becomes sheetname!A:A.  in your case my example C:C is representing your column AF on Visual, so references to C:C would become VISUAL!AF:AF.  If your reference is on the same sheet as the formula, you do not need to put the sheet name...wont hurt, but not needed either.